# find ALL conformal map with a certain property

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on this problem from a qualifying exam of some years ago. It reads: find all conformal transformations sending the upper half disc of radius 2, $\{z: |z|<2\}$ to the unit disc, with the property that $f(i)=0$. You may just write the solution as composition of simpler functions.

It is not hard to find one such conformal map: shrinking the half disc by a factor 2, and applying subsequently $(\dfrac{-1}{2})(z+\dfrac{1}{z})$ sends the half disc to the upper half plane and $i$ to $(3/4)i$. Hence the map $\dfrac{z-(3/4)i}{z+(3/4)i}$ does the job.

What I'm struggling with is the "all" part of the theorem. My nose suggests that there is only this one, but how can I prove/disprove it? More generally, is there a set of more or less standardized techniques to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: Hint: What are the conformal self-maps of the unit disk fixing $0$?

Comment: I see. By Scwharz lemma, they're rotations. And by the Riemann mapping theorem, up to rotation there's only one map, the one I showed. Thanks!